# checking for Linear Independence in sets of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a quick question regarding LI in sets of R3 vectors.

lets say I have a set of two vectors like (6,-3,0), (-10,5,0) in R3

I know that if k1*v1 + k2*v2 = (0,0,0) and the only solution for k1,k2 is 0,0, then it is Linearly Independent.

I also know that if I have 3 or more vectors in R3, I can make a system of equations, by placing the vectors vertically into the matrix, take the determinant (add a row of 0's if its more than 3 vectors), if it = 0? its LD, otherwise LI. (is this correct?)

I want to set the vectors as system and find the determinant to check for LD, but theres only 2 of them, so I have a matrix like:

6 -10 = 0

-3 5 = 0

0 0 = 0

so I have a feeling I'm not allowed to take the determinant of this. whats the quickest way to test for LI if you only have 2 vectors in R3?

Comment: take determinant of a minor and if its not zero then the vectors are LI.

Comment: isn't a minor where you cross off an entire row and column? in this case it looks like I could only take the determinant of [6,-10, -3,5] (clockwise)

Comment: so does crossing off one row of a 3x2 matrix making it a 2x2 matrix count as a minor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $v_1=(6,-3,0)$ and $v_2= (-10,5,0)$. But $v_1=3(2,-1,0)$, $v_2=-5(2,-1,0)$, hence they are linearly dependent.

Comment: i can see that now. my real question is if I can just figure this out by turning a 3x2 matrix into a 2x2 matrix by dropping a row and taking the determinant.

Comment: @JL You are close to a good method. However you should consider all $2\times2$ matrices, at least to show dependency. It is connected with so called rank: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29 (I understand, that you have not this definition yet). But of course, when you can see, that the first vecor is proportional to the second, it is **the quickest** way. :-)

Comment: what do you mean when you say i should consider all 2x2 matrices at least to show dependency? if I'm close to a good method, can you tell me what about my method is broken? I'm also really concerned about when I can't see the vector is proportional to the first one.

Comment: @JL If there exists a nonzero minor od degree (here) 2, then there are 2 independent vectors. There are 3 such subdeterminats, hence it is not enough to check if only one of them is nonzero. Adding a zero column to obtain determinant of degree 3 is unneeded. (If it is a standard linear algebra course, the method, using rank, should appear). To see a possible problem, think about vectors, say, $(6,-3,3)$, $(-10,5,-5)$.

Comment: im not sure, but did you make a typo meaning "nonzero minor of degree (here) 2"? I'm also confused on a couple things in your comment. what exactly is a nonzero minor? and do you mean the 3 such subdeterminants are the first 2 rows, the second 2 rows, and the first and third row? and when you say adding a third column is un needed, does that mean I'm always allowed to add a third column to make it a 3x3 and take the determinant of that, then if its 0 its LD, and not its LI?

Comment: third column of 0's* I mean.

Comment: @JL I hope that you have read something about computing a rank. 1) A minor is a subdeterminant obtained by deleting some number of columns and rows in the original matrix. Hence the minors of degree 2 are exactly as you write. 2) Nonzero minor is such, that is value is not 0. 3) No, you cannot add anything. Simply if one column (verse) of determinant is a zero vector, the determinant is equal to 0. Hence my example, where the value of determinants is not so obvious (although equal to 0).

Comment: ok so: I read how to compute rank, by reducing the matrix to RREF and the number of non zero rows is the rank. but I think it would be easier to take determinants. so I'm not allowed to add a column of 0s, (or add a zero vector to the set), but I am allowed to take 3 minor determinants, and if any of them are not 0 (or as you say, if any of them are non zero minors?) its LI. If they are all 0 its LD. is this all correct?

Comment: @JL Yes! :-) (Of course in the case of $2\times 3$ matrix).

Comment: thank you! i now know everything I need to know for most of the rest of my homework for now. I also feel a lot more enlightened about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Remember $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent if $c_1v_1+c_2v_2=0$ if and only if $c_1=c_2=0$.

So (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) you want to know if

$$c_1(6,-3,0)+c_2(-10,5,0)=(0,0,0)$$

has only the zero solution. But this is equivalent to the system of equations

\begin{align}
6c_1-10c_2&=0,\\
-3c_1+5c_2&=0,\\
0c_1+0c_2&=0,
\end{align}

which yields

$c_2={3\over 5}c_1$ for any $c_1$ so $c_1=c_2=0$ is *not* the only solution and hence these vectors are linearly dependent.

---

If you want to bring determinants into the conversation, note the $2\times 2$ system above is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -10\\
-3 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1\\
c_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and it will have a nontrivial solution if and only if $\det A=0$ where $A$ would be the $2\times 2$ matrix on the left above. Since the determinant here is $(6)(5)-(-10)(-3)=0$, we again confirm that there is a nontrivial solution to this system and hence the two vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: thats good, I understand all of this completely. I just want to be sure I can quickly figure out LI or LD on any 2 vectors in R3. I'm starting to think I can do so by adding a third column of 0's and taking the 3x3 determinant, where 0=LD and =/=0 = LI. is this true? similarly, I'm also thinking I can take the determinant of the first two 2x2 rows, the second two 2x2 rows, and the first/third 2x2 rows, if they are all 0, then its LD, if any of them is not 0, then LI. Is this true?

Comment: You can only do the determinant of a square matrix. If you force the matrix to be square by appending a column of zeros, it will necessarily have a zero determinant, so that doesn't help. What you *can* do for nonsquare matrices is compute its rank. Have you studied rank? If not, what about echelon form or reduced echelon form or row reduced echelon form of a (not necessarily square) matrix?

Comment: we haven't gone over ranks yet. but it appears that taking minors of non square matrices will always suffice for determining LI/LD.